# How to find the corners of a quadrilateral by known coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I have a task in which you need to find the perimeter of a quadrilateral.I wrote the function `perimetr` in which I have to get the perimeter. On output i get `3.0`, it's incorrect.The correct answer is 10.0.

What did I do wrong?

My code:

```
import re
from math import pow,sqrt

def perimetr(data):
    x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3,x4,y4 = map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', data))
    print(x1,y1)
    print(x2, y2)
    print(x3, y3)
    print(x4, y4)
    return sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2) *2

test1 = "#LB1:1#RB4:1#LT1:3#RT4:3"
print(perimetr(test1)
```

)

Comment: I would suggest you to split your problem. First compute the distance between two points. Then, the perimeter is the sum of the distance between all consecutive vertices.

Comment: `sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)` is the distance between points `LB` and `RB`. Multiply that by 2 and you have accounted for the bottom and top edges of the quadrilateral, provided it's a rectangle. What about the left and right edges? What about if the bottom and top edges aren't equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The perimeter of a quadrilateral is:

```py
sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2) + sqrt((x2-x4)**2 + (y2-y4)**2) + sqrt((x4-x3)**2 + (y4-y3)**2) + sqrt((x3-x1)**2 + (y3-y1)**2)
```

But you should probably improve the parsing of your function because it is not robust

"#LB1:1#RB4:1#LT1:3#RT4:3" is the same as "#LB1:1#RB4:1#RT4:3#LT1:3" but your code would output the wrong result